# CPanel Users transfer, but don't show up in WHM

Tags: cpanel, control-panel, whm

I'm having an unusual issue with WHM. I experienced issues with a server that is currently running WHM, so I setup a new one and used the transfer tool to migrate accounts over. For some reason several accounts transferred successfully, but do not show up in the 'list accounts' section of WHM. I cannot figure out what these accounts have in common as this is a very basic setup that is only running a few personal accounts. Any thoughts on what could be the issue here?

Comment: I would suggest that despite the apparent successful transfer they haven't really.  Did you try again?

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I tried several times and the log always showed a successful transfer. I can even see the user accounts in the Linux system. They just won't show up in CPanel.

Comment: My guess is that it is some sort of account problem. i.e. they are being pulled into a different account to the one you are looking at.  Can't think of anything else.  Sorry

Comment: There might be some clues at the bottom of this page: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1148Docs/Copy+an+Account+from+Another+Server+with+Account+Password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The Linux UID's corresponding to each of the users in question were below 1000. I simply raised them all to be over 1000 and restarted CPanel, and everything worked like magic.